# A macros which prints name of variables and its values

Tags: c++, macros

I can define a macros which print only fixed variable count, for example:

```
#define PRINT_PARAMS(param) std::cout << "test: " << std::string( #param ) << " = " << param << "\n";

// using:
int varI = 5;
PRINT_PARAMS( varI );

// output:
test: varI = 5
```

How to define a macros which will do something like that:

```
PRINT_PARAMS( varI1, strValue2, floatValue3, doubleValue4 );

// output:
varI1 = 5, strValue2 = some string, floatValue3 = 3.403f, ....
```

I mean any number of input parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//"for each" macro iterations
#define FE_1(Y, X) Y(X) 
#define FE_2(Y, X, ...) Y(X)FE_1(Y, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_3(Y, X, ...) Y(X)FE_2(Y, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_4(Y, X, ...) Y(X)FE_3(Y, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FE_5(Y, X, ...) Y(X)FE_4(Y, __VA_ARGS__)
//... repeat as needed

//the "for each" call
#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,NAME,...) NAME 
#define FOR_EACH(action,...) \
  GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__,FE_5,FE_4,FE_3,FE_2,FE_1)(action,__VA_ARGS__)

//function to print a single
#define PRINT_SINGLE(param) std::cout << "test: " << std::string( #param ) << " = " << param << "\n";

//function to print n amount
#define PRINT_PARAMS(...) FOR_EACH(PRINT_SINGLE,__VA_ARGS__)

int main(){
  std::string s1 = "hello";
  float f = 3.14;
  int i = 42;
  PRINT_PARAMS(s1,f,i)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a compiler to hand but was wondering if the following variadic macro would work (or at least help give you an idea.)

```
#define PRINT_PARAMS(param) std::cout << "test: " << std::string( #param ) << " = " << param << "\n";

#define PRINT_PARAMS(a, ...) { PRINT_PARAMS((a)); PRINT_PARAMS(__VA_ARGS__); }
```

Comment: That would expand the following way:  `{ PRINT_PARAMS((var1)); PRINT_PARAMS(var2,var3,var4); }`

Comment: @TrevorHickey - yes, I was expecting that and will that then call PRINT_PARAMS(a, ...) again ?  just like in template meta programming? It has been ages since I wrote a variadic macro but from the look of your answer below you seem to have lots of experience :)

Comment: Ah, I wish that were true, otherwise my answer wouldn't have been so complicated.  
"If the expansion of a macro contains its own name, either directly or via intermediate macros, it is not expanded again when the expansion is examined for more macros."